# Finding the syscalls associated with a number

Tags: ptrace

I am tracing a program using ptrace. After stopping on a syscall, I use PTRACE_PEEKUSER to look at the value of (ORIG_)EAX. Actually RAX since I'm 64 bit.

What is a good way of translating this into the appropriate value?
For example 2-> "open" ( IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own table mapping the numbers to the names.  I don't think there's any other way.  I've often wished otherwise, but...  Also, note that the mappings are arch-dependent.